# ConcurrentDictionary - AddOrUpdate issue

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I'm using this code below to try to update the values in a dictionary object depending on its key.

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, SingleUserStatisticsViewModel> UsersViewModel = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SingleUserStatisticsViewModel>();

var userSession = new UserSessionStatistic()
{
    Id = "12345", Browser = "Netscape"
};
var userViewModel = new SingleUserStatisticsViewModel()
{
    UserSessionStatistic = userSession,
    StartTime = DateTime.Now
};
```

//Add first time

```
MyStaticClass.UsersViewModel.AddOrUpdate(userViewModel.UserSessionStatistic.Id, userViewModel, (key, model) => model);
```

//try to Update

```
        var userSession2 = new UserSessionStatistic()
        {
            Id = "12345",
            Browser = "not getting updated????"
        };
        var userViewModel2 = new SingleUserStatisticsViewModel()
        {
            UserSessionStatistic = userSession2,
            StartTime = DateTime.Now
        };

MyStaticClass.UsersViewModel.AddOrUpdate(userViewModel2.UserSessionStatistic.Id, userViewModel2, (key, model) => model);
```

But the `UsersessionStatistic` object in `userViewModel2` is not getting updated in the ConcurrentDictionary (it's Browser propery still says `"Netscape"`), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are adding to the same ConcurrentDictionary ? (beacause MyStaticClass != SignalRStatic). Seeing your code, it should work...

Comment: @Sharped . Yeah I'm 100% shure it's same ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: @Sharped.  Oh, sorry that's just a a typo. I fix it

Comment: Ok, that's because of the lambda. The lambda pass the old value as parameter => (key, oldValue) => oldValue

Comment: Look at msdn => https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee378665.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the value factory, [the docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378664.aspx):

> updateValueFactory Type: System.Func The
>   function used to generate a new value for an existing key based on the
>   key's **existing value**

Which means your passing it the existing value. You need to update it with the new one instead:

```
MyStaticClass.UsersViewModel.AddOrUpdate(userViewModel2.UserSessionStatistic.Id,
                                         userViewModel2, 
                                         (key, oldModel) => userViewModel2);
```